# SQL Agent: Suppressing errors until all job attempts fail

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a SQL job that fails maybe twice a day when it tries to write a file that the next process down the line needs. Our solution was to set the attempts to 10. It almost never goes past 2 attempts before succeeding. Is there a way to suppress error messages unless all attempts fail?

Comment: Tell us about the job step that writes to a file.  Is it an SSIS package?  ActiveX script?  PowerShell script?  If it's something like that, you could add (or enhance) error handling in the package/script to include error counters.  If/When the error counter reaches the threshold of 10 attempts, throw the error (back to SQL Agent).

Comment: It's a simple file copy task in SSIS. If there's an easy way to embed that in the package, we wouldn't have to get messages until it actually failed.